# Organic malt sources

Tags: malt

Aside from Northern Brewer, where on line can I find organic malt?  I can usually get organic base malt at my LHBS, but sources for crystal and other malts seem to have largely dried up.

Answer (score 1):

The Weyermann BIOLAND organic specialty malts might be out of stock everywhere.  Distributor BSG has several websites, on their BSG craftbrewing site they list 13 Weyermann organic base and specialty and caramel malts, but on the BSG handcraft site they list just pils, rye and Vienna.  BSG has a Find a Retailer page, too, so you could call around.  Maybe BSG would answer an email or phone call asking whether they expect one of their retailers might have stock.

Good luck.